# Synchronising SoundCloud audio and Vimeo/Youtube video playing together

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, audio, soundcloud

Alright, I'm working on one project which involves html5 audio, in addition to that a video is shown while audio is playing (Just video, no controls etc). Video is a visualisation (sometimes called equaliser) of audio that is playing, made beforehand in adobe after effects. both files (video and audio) are same length e.g. 3 min 20 sec. I need a way to synchronise both, as video might load slower than audio or vice versa. Therefore I need to make it so that on computers with slow internet connection if video stops loading at some point and starts buffering I need to pause audio, and once video resumes start audio again, both at exactly same time, also when user skips to a certain bit in a song, video should skip to that bit as well, I'll use custom api made player for video so there would be no controls on video, only on soundcloud player.
It is almost as if I was using soundcloud custom player to control video. I'm struggling to find any resources on this anywhere, and would really like to know how to achieve this functionality.
javascript or jQuery solutions are preferable.

What makes it even more complicated is that I use SoundCloud's custom player to play songs:
http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/custom-player#

And upload videos to Vimeo/YouTube (all done to decrease load on a website)

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just add the audio to the video file and not worry about syncing with Soundcloud's player at all?

Comment: Several, First I need to give users option to just listen audio and not load video if they are on slow internet, also copyright issues associated with uploading music videos, where as if I use sound cloud to stream music and show my custom video with no sound, it is not an issue.

Comment: Just use Pink Floyd's Dark Side of the Moon.  (:Apparently it syncs with anything:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check here: http://html5demos.com/two-videos

The sample is for syncing 2 videos, but with some hacking probably you can manage to sync audio and video.

Second, don't use Custom player, make your own HTML5 Audio element, check the [SoundCloud API](http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/reference#tracks) there is a property stream_url for every streamable track on soundcloud, just put that URL as source on your html5 audio tag.

Keep on mind that this will not work on Firefox and Opera for some time. Firefox will integrate native mp3 support in v20, not sure about opera